# ajax request :document.getElementByID('txtHint).innerHTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I have following in my HTML code:

```
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

and I have following in my JavaScript:

```
document.getElementByID('txtHint').innerHTML = 'hi';
```

I have a problem; the code stops executing at the above JavaScript line. The statements following the above JavaScript line are not executed. However, statements preceding that line are correctly executed. I have checked this by using the `alert` function.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change that to `getElementById` with a lowercase `'d'`.